# Regex to remove strings from list that do not match given prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string that includes multiple comma-separated lists of values, always embedded between `<mks:Field name="MyField">` and `</mks:Field>`.

For example:

```
<mks:Field name="MyField">X001_ABC</mks:Field><mks:Field name="AnotherField">X002_XYZ</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField"></mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1,X000_Test2</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X001_ABC,X000_Test1</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1,X000_Test2,X002_XYZ</mks:Field>
```

In this example I have the following values to work with:

- X001_ABC
- (empty)
- X000_Test1,X000_Test2
- X001_ABC,X000_Test1
- X000_Test1,X000_Test2,X002_XYZ

Now I want to remove all the values that do not start with the prefix ""X000_", including any needless commas, so that my result looks like this:

```
<mks:Field name="MyField"></mks:Field><mks:Field name="AnotherField">X002_XYZ</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField"></mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1,X000_Test2</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1,X000_Test2</mks:Field>
```

I have tried the following regex, but it does not work properly if only one value exists not matching  my regex and I do not want to change my regex if a new value matching my prefix is introduced (e.g. X000_Test3).

Search: `(?<=name="MyField">)[^<>](?:.*?(X000_Test1,X000_Test2|X000_Test1|X000_Test2))?.*?(?=</mks:Field>)`

Replace: `\1`

This gives me the following result that does not match the expected output:

```
<mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1,X000_Test2</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test1</mks:Field><mks:Field name="MyField">X000_Test2</mks:Field>
```

Unfortunately I cannot simply parse the string with something else - I only have the option of a regex search/replace in this case.

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to remove all values that do not start with `X000_` try https://regex101.com/r/LNqg9t/1/ What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your regex does exactly what I want! Unfortunately the tool runs the regex in python (sorry, I have added the tag now) and as far as I see python does not support \G and \K. Any idea on how I can get around this without having access to the python script itself? Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Can you install the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript use this:

```
prefix='X000';

let pattern= new RegExp(`((?<=>)|,)((?!${prefix}|[>\<,]).)*(,|(?=\<))`, 'g');
```

For any other language use this:

```
'/((?<=>)|,)((?!X000|[>\<,]).)*(,|(?=\<))/';
```

X000 being the prefix you want to keep